# how can i manage unread badge count using qucikblox in iOS?

Tags: quickblox

I am using latest SDK of quickblox. So can you let me know how i can get the un-read badge count in the iOS device.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should also include what you've already tried and where you are stuck so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the application icon badge number, you can use this approach:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber.
```

If you're asking about dialogs unread count, then you should use the property `unreadMessagesCount` of the class instance of `QBChatDialog`